# Cannot pass selfmade serializable object to another activity via intent

Tags: java, android, object, android-intent

I created an object which contains data fields of the types ImageView, boolean and Integer.

```
public class MemoryCard implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {

    private ImageView image;
    private int id;
    private int nr;
    private boolean clicked = false;
    private int cardBack;
    private int cardFront;

    public MemoryCard(Context context, int id, int nr, int cardFront)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.nr = nr;
        this.cardBack = R.drawable.backside;
        this.cardFront = cardFront;
        this.image = new ImageView(context);
        this.image.setImageResource(this.cardBack);
        this.image.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

When I start to send an object from MainActivity to SecondActivity then an error occurs and my App stops running.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("object", new MemoryCard(this, 0, 0, R.drawable.myImage));

startActivity(intent);
```

I think it has something to do with the parameters **this** and **R.drawable.myImage** of the **MemoryCard** constructor but why?

Comment: Why not just sending Class object which hold all required data in next Activity to show `ImageView` instead of sending `ImageView` object ?

Comment: "my App stops running" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this As others have pointed out, most likely, you are crashing on the `ImageView`, as that cannot be serialized. `SecondActivity` has no means of modifying the UI of `MainActivity` directly, which is my guess as to what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

Is `ImageView` serializable? An object if serializable only if it implements `Serializable` **and** all its members are serializable.

Comment: Is it possible to make ImageView serializiable as well?

Comment: @RamónWilhelm pass the image url not the imageview