# Is it possible to send an ImageView to another Activity via GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, android-imageview, gson

I want to find out if there is a way to send an entire ImageView to another activity. Is it possible to achieve that with GSON?

Comment: Sending the `ImageView` itself would be a bad idea and not possible anyway. Instead, you could send a path to the image.

Comment: ImageView or Bitmap?

Comment: Given this question and [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148045/cannot-pass-selfmade-serializable-object-to-another-activity-via-intent), you may have better luck if you ask a question where you explain what you are trying to achieve, at a high level, and ask for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping it in a class that implements Parcelable, but I think sending an entire view element to another activity is not really the way to go... Just send the image url and then load an image to an imageview in the other activity.